# Laravel : POST method data can't retrieve for non-authenticate user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to put my post method data into session and redirect it to login page for non-authenticate user. But if the user is authenticate i can dd() the $product but for non-authenticate user i couldn't retrieve the $name and so couldn't put the the name into session ..Why is that?

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'downloadFree','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
            {!! Form::token(); !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('name',$product->name) !!}
                    <button type="submit" id="buyNow" name="buyNow" class="btn " style="width: 100%; height: 45px;" title="Download Now"><i class="icon icon-action-redo"></i>
                    Free Download
                    </button>
            {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Route::

```
Route::post('downloadFree','ProductController@downloadFree')->name('downloadFree');
```

Controller code:

```
 if(Auth::user())
    {
        $name = $request->name;
        $product = Product::where('name', '=', $name)->first(); 
        dd($product);
    }
    else
    {   $name = $request->name;
        $product = Product::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
        dd($name);       // nothing came & redirect to ('/') page 
        \Session::put('name',$request->name);
    return redirect('/login')->with('warning',"Login first to Download");
    }
```

Comment: And please show code where you set session for $product->name

Comment: skip the session part.first it should come to the else condition right?
i should see the $product if I dd() the output ?

Comment: yes please display dd($request->name) outside of if condition

Comment: when i dd($request->name) it redirects me to index means Home page.
but when it logged in i can see the name means dd() works!

Comment: please check name field have value or not {!! Form::text('name',$product->name) !!} please check it

Comment: Yes name has the value ..I inspected it

Comment: I was post my answer and please change as per my answer and post the form and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with this:

Please change

```
{!! Form::hidden('name',$product->name) !!}
```

to

```
{!! Form::text('name',$product->name,['style'=>'display:none;']) !!}
```

### Update

As you able to get result of `dd($request->all())` into `downloadFree` method only with user loggedin but not without it. Means that your routes restricted by middleware which not allow you to post data without logged in.

Comment: Nope same thing happening .when i dd($request->name) it redirects me to index means Home page. but when it logged in i can see the name means dd() works!

Comment: @User57 Please show controller code for display form

Comment: Controller code is same as i have posted with Question

Comment: @User57 Please provide you get and post route

Comment: Ok, just place `dd($request->all());` at first line of `downloadFree()` method and let me know what this print?

Comment: Nope same thing happening .when i dd($request->all()) it redirects me to index means Home page. but when it logged in i can see the name means dd() works!

Comment: Means that your routes restricted by middleware which not allow you to post data without logged in....

Comment: Can you update your answer..so i could mark it as correct..means your last point solved it ;)